# Enhance layout integration of react-select into material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I'm using the new material-ui 4.0(.1) and I want to push forward the [react-select integration documented in the official docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#react-select).

What is missing is a user interface support for the disabled status (`isDisabled` prop from react-select). The disable status works, but there's no good materialui style integration for it.

If I look at a [classic select component](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#simple-select) I see that a disabled one is:

- grayed font
- bottom line is *dotted*

[image: Default select disabled style]

So, I want to have the same behavior for the react-select once.

Without manually customizing the styles, I see that simply adding the `Mui-disabled` CSS class on the proper div does the trick using the browser inspector.

[image: DOM for react-select disabled with Mui-disabled class]

[image: react-select disabled with Mui-disabled class]

So this is probably the best way to go, so I automatically inherith the disabled style, but I cannot find a way to inject this class at that div.

Is this possible someway or it's better for me to just manually re-apply the style?

By copy-pasting the code from the documentation seems that the core of the issue is in this snippet:

```
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      className="Mui-disabled"
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent,
        inputProps: {
          className: clsx(props.selectProps.classes.input, {
            'Mui-disabled': true,
          }),
          inputRef: props.innerRef,
          children: props.children,
          ...props.innerProps,
        },
      }}
      {...props.selectProps.TextFieldProps}
    />
  );
```

(hard-coded `Mui-disabled`here is just for text purpose).

Unluckily both `Mui-disabled` classes attempt fails. They are added to the direct container and direct children of the proper node.

[image: Mui-disabled on unproper positions]

Looking at the code of FormControl at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/60071b8b6d4406af3c0a7a332ff86ca02cffa32d/packages/material-ui/src/FormControl/FormControl.js#L149 (the component that's render the `div` I need to modify) I see no way of doing this.

**Please note** I'm perfectly aware that simply customizing the style is an order of magnitude simpler, but I'm still learning the whole framework here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do one of two things:

1. Provide `disabled: true` to `TextFieldProps`:

```
<Select
    classes={classes}
    styles={selectStyles}
    isDisabled={true}
    TextFieldProps={{
        label: 'Label',
        disabled: true, //<---- add this row
        InputLabelProps: {
            shrink: true,
        },
    }}
    options={suggestions}
    components={components}
    value={multi}
    onChange={handleChangeMulti}
    placeholder="Select multiple countries"
    isMulti
/>
```

2. Or slightly change `Control` component:

```
function Control(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent,
        inputProps: {
          className: props.selectProps.classes.input,
          inputRef: props.innerRef,
          children: props.children,
          ...props.innerProps,
        },
      }}
      disabled={props.isDisabled} //<---- add this row
      {...props.selectProps.TextFieldProps}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great... I'll go for the number two. Meanwhile I was testing another workaround that was to pass `className: isDisabled ? 'Mui-disabled' : undefined` to `InputProps` prop but this is _a lot_ cleaner. Thanks!